# CreateProcess with current privilege

Tags: c++, process

I have a setup file that when run will prompt for UAC (assume it is enabled) and this setup file  will run another exe that require UAC too however I don't want the second exe to ask for UAC permission, so how do I inherit current elevated privileges to child process in C++

Comment: According to the UAC specification, "Each application that requires the administrator’s access token must prompt the administrator for consent. The one exception is the relationship that exists between parent and child processes. Child processes will inherit the user’s access token from their parents. Both the parent and child processes, however, must have the same integrity level." Are you saying this is not true? Or are you starting the child process at a different integrity level?

Comment: My questions :How to start a child process? I dont understand about integrity level, how to set it? and what kind of code makes the software have different integrity level?

Comment: For your situation I don't think it will matter. Once your parent process has acquired the proper elevated privilege its child process should inherit it. What you can NOT do is start the parent, have it start the child, *then* elevate the parent. The child will have its own at that point. See MS's documentation on CreateProcess() and the user token-management function family for more info. its a pretty well documented set of APIs.

Comment: hi thanks WhozCraig, I have figured a way to do it, I use CreateProcessWithTokenW and duplicating the token of high integrity process. It will success only when current process run in high integrity. Thanks. Btw do you know how to start debug in visual studio where the program is run in high integrity?