# Can CreateProcess() give admin rights?

Tags: c++, windows, administrator, createprocess

If program A is Executed as administrator by the user, can program A use the CreateProcess() windows function to launch program B with admin rights?
Thank you in advance

Comment: [*The new process runs in the security context of the calling process.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess with current privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12614871/11683)

Comment: all rights concentrated in process token. new process inherit token from parent. parent process usual is creator process (who call `CreateProcess`) unless `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` used with direct parent process handle

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply Yes. You can start another program as Administrator if the launching program runs elevated.